# How can I call Liferay.Service from react-portlet

Tags: reactjs, liferay, liferay-7

I've he example code from react-portlet in liferay 7.4 and a custom object called Pruebas. In swagger appear /o/c/pruebas, but I want to get all items with liferay object because authentication is required for this. I've this code

```
Liferay.Service('pruebas', {},
    function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
)
```